# How to expand div correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when i expand div. When i expand menu on left side one items moves to right side, and when i expand div on right side it also expand my left side. How can i stop that? This is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/LLkaj4h0/7/

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel-group row" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

     <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          1. Finansijski menadžment <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
          2. Javne finansije - budžet i trezor <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          3. Računovodstveno savjetovanje <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
          4. Korporativno - poslovno pravo <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          5. Porezno savjetovanje <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSeven">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSeven">
          6. EU fondovi <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSeven">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
          7. Usaglašavanje zakonodavstva sa pravom Evropske unije <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each pairing into their own row: https://jsfiddle.net/LLkaj4h0/8/

```
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel-group row" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

     <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          1. Finansijski menadžment <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
          2. Javne finansije - budžet i trezor <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-group row" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          3. Računovodstveno savjetovanje <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
          4. Korporativno - poslovno pravo <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-group row" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          5. Porezno savjetovanje <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSeven">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSeven">
          6. EU fondovi <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSeven">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-group row" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
          7. Usaglašavanje zakonodavstva sa pravom Evropske unije <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="expand-details">
            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but again when i click on right menu it add heigt on left side

Comment: OK, but the issue before was that the div below was going to the right wasn't it? That's now fixed. Because each of of div's are in the same row, the row will expand to the height of its tallest child, this is expected behavior...

Comment: i know why is doing that but can i somehow stop that?

Comment: and now when i expand right menu it not close left menu